# how i clone a especific li to another ul

Tags: jquery

How do I clone a `li` in another `ul`, not exceeding the number of `li` that I have on the other `ul`?

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

I have to clone to

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

without repeat a `li` and until to complete 3 elements

Here is my jquery code

```
var total = $(this).find('.contentSecond ul li').length;
$('first.content ul li').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= total; i++) {
        $(this).clone().appendTo($('.contentSecond ul'));
    }
    return false;
});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is `$(this)` on the first line? And if the second `<ul>` is empty, `length` will be `0`, so the `for` loop won't do anything.

Comment: Please provide enough HTML and code so we can actually try to execute it. Make a stack snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Explanation is really lacking in detail. Code appears like you want to move all when one is clicked. WHat does `until to complete 3 elements` mean? Complete sentences would help